# ListView rounded Selector

Tags: android

I have create a listView with rounded cornered background. Now while i select the first item in the listview, the selector shape was not top rounded rect. Likewise while i select the last item in listview, the selector shape was not bottom rounded rect. If i apply rounded rect to the selector all listview item selection will be rounded rect shape. So that i want the selector shape to be matched with the listview's rounded rect background.

Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Not sure if you still need it, but i have created a android library for that. Check this out [UITableView for Android](https://github.com/thiagolocatelli/android-uitableview)

Answer (score 0):

By default list view  is of rectangle shape. But we can overwrite it and give the shape to list items. But as the default shape is rectangle so we can't overwrite that in selector.
    I did face this problem. But there is no other way to change the list view selector shape. 
    It is android's default feature.

Comment: No i have solved this problem.
http://www.anddev.org/view-layout-resource-problems-f27/rounded-corners-on-listview-t8193.html